# Vue cards render picture twice

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a news site that renders each card and picture twice.

https://codepen.io/Teeke/pen/QWKQydz

There's a component called doubleUp

```
   created() {
    this.doubleUp()
   },
```

do these two lines render the picture twice?:

```
    newImage.id  = image.id * 2
        this.images.push(newImage)
```

I've tried changing the * 2 value to * 1, or * 6. But it makes no difference to the amount of cards rendered. I'm not sure why the picture is rendering twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `doubleUp` function makes your images displayed twice. `this.images` already have images array. And you pushed every images once again foreach
loop.

```
doubleUp() {
  //fake a bunch of data
  let localImages = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.images))

  localImages.forEach((image) => {
    let newImage = image
    newImage.id  = image.id * 2
    this.images.push(newImage)
  })

  setTimeout(() => {
    this.loading = false
    //then run replacePleaceholders
    this.replacePlaceholders()
  }, 200)
},
```

If you want to keep images array the same and only want to doubleup `id`, you have to do like this.

```
doubleUp() {
  //fake a bunch of data
  let localImages = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.images))
  this.images = []; // <------------------------
  localImages.forEach((image) => {
    let newImage = image
    newImage.id  = image.id * 2
    this.images.push(newImage)
  })

  setTimeout(() => {
    this.loading = false
    //then run replacePleaceholders
    this.replacePlaceholders()
  }, 200)
},
```